# TypeScript - Next Auth adapter error when changing the default User interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next-auth

I'm using TypeScript for the first time. So I'm trying to change the default User interface for `next-auth`.

I've tried the following code:

next-auth.d.ts

```js
import { User } from "next-auth"
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"

type UserId = string

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    id: UserId
    firstName: string
    email: string
  }
}

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    firstName: string
  }
}
```

When I do that however the `adapter` option for `next-auth` gets an error:

[image]

Here is a link to the full error: https://gist.github.com/DantchoLV9/47c92be7d66c2d0e0bfd2bf0d56120bd

I did also try to add a `?` after `firstName` so the code looks like this:

next-auth.d.ts

```js
import { User } from "next-auth"
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"

type UserId = string

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    id: UserId
    firstName: string
    email: string
  }
}

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    firstName?: string
  }
}
```

It seems like this solves the issue at least partly. (The `adapter` doesn't error, however other code that uses the User interface get affected)

What am I doing wrong and is the solution I used apropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem, and I find that the reason is due to the import of prisma adapter.

It seems that you had use in your **authOptions file**:

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter"
```

Instead of that **open your command terminal** and put `npm install @next-auth/prisma-adapter`

And **after that replace it with:**

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
```